# Float issues in ie8 - Position and width did not solve issue (using Zurb Foundation)

Tags: internet-explorer-8, css-float, zurb-foundation

References are all to: http://smartgridcanadaconf.ca/2013/
I am having a float issue in ie8 that I have not been able to resolve by giving widths to items in my header - I've tried playing with position as well - So at this point - Here comes my first question on StackOverflow -

**How do I get the date line in the header to be inline with with the "save the date" button? **

The site is built using ZURB FOUNDATION, version 4, which features box-sizing - I have some css to remedy those issues from this Gist and comments https://gist.github.com/zurbchris/5068210

I realize I can use the grid to solve this problem to a degree - However, I do want to figure out what else I should be looking for when trying to float elements ie8.

```
<section class="whiteOut whiteBG row">
  <div class="small-12 large-12 columns whiteBG">
    <ul id="socialnetworks" class="hide-for-small right">

        <li class="icon-linkedin-sign linkedinBtn icon-2x text-center"><a href="http://www.linkedin.com/groups/Smart-Grid-Canada-Conference-4018849?trk=myg_ugrp_ovr"></a></li>
        <li class="twitterBtn icon-twitter icon-2x text-center"><a href="https://twitter.com/CanadaSmartGrid"></a></li>
        <li class="mailBtn icon-envelope icon-2x text-center"><a href="maito:anne-marie.enns@sgcanada.org"></a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="date">
      <li style="width:337px" class="left">
        <h2>September 23-25th, 2013</h2>
        <a href="#"></a> </li>
      <li style="width:105px" class="left"> <a href="http://smartgridcanadaconf.ca/2013/?attachment_id=78"><span class="saveDate label"><i class="icon-calendar"></i> <span class="hide-for-small">Save to Calendar</span></span></a> </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This may be far too bloated a fix [but at the Zurb blog they also mention another way](http://zurb.com/article/1204/getting-foundation-and-ie8-to-play-nice): serving different versions of Foundation.

```
<!-- Foundation 3 for IE 8 and earlier -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/foundation3/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/foundation3/foundation.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/foundation3/app.css">
<![endif]-->
<!-- Foundation 4 for IE 9 and earlier -->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/foundation4/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/foundation4/foundation.css">
<!--<![endif]-->
```

And after the close body tag:

```
<!-- Foundation 3 for IE 8 and earlier -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="/js/foundation3/foundation.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/foundation3/app.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<!-- Foundation 4 for IE 9 and later -->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
   <script src="/js/foundation4/foundation.min.js"></script>
   <script>
    $(document).foundation();
   </script>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

The layout markup just combines the F4 and F3 grid classes:

`<div class="twelve large-12 columns">`

Comment: That would work - but the problem was solved by removing: *,
*:before,
*:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box; }

Answer (score 0):

Box-Sizing is an obvious issue in ie8 - but I was also having problems in Safari. Problem was solved by removing ... from css:

```
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box; }
```

This also resolved the malfunctioning of FREETILEjs - which was not working in Safari and loading slowly in all browsers.